# Single pulse when circuit is powered on

Tags: pulse

I am new to electronics and I am wondering how can I use my Vcc to produce a short single pulse.

Comment: just a pulse close to your Vcc voltage?

Comment: yes close to my Vcc will do

Comment: It depends on what the pulse is driving. Please edit your question to explain what the real problem is.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on your definition of short, and close, a single cap and resistor can do the job:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1t22B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

You can play with C1 and R1 to achieve the desired shape.

Comment: Maybe it is better to add that this circuit produces  a positive pulse (+Vcc) when power is applied, but a negative one (up to -Vcc) when it is removed, which may cause issues to the circuit after this. In this case, adding a diode (anode to ground, cathode to PULSE pin) can solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try using a 555 IC in the monostable configuration, with this circuit you will be able to drive small loads, e.g., LEDs and logic circuits.
Take a look at [555 IC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC)
It will give a response like this one

[image: wikipedia on the 555 monostable circuit response]

and the circuit is this one

[image: wikipedia on the 555 monostable circuit]

where you should keep the trigger pin high (above \$V_{CC}/3\$) until the moment you want the pulse, at this time you should send a 0V signal to it, this circuit would do it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f27b8C.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What is triggering the pulse?

Comment: you have to put a momentary button connecting the trigger pin to ground, I will add the circuit